# Dynamically create multiple instances of the same component.

Tags: javascript, angular5

Is there a way to dynamically create multiple instances of the same component in angular? I have tried it using componentFacory, but no success.

Comment: What problems did you run into? Can you provide any code showing how you did it?

Comment: I just created a simplified example on stackblitz and it actually worked. Must have done something wrong when trying it in our app. Anyway, if anyone wants to know how here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4aus6a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private helloRef: ComponentRef<HelloComponent>;
private byeRef: ComponentRef<GoodbyeComponent>;
private helloCopyRef: ComponentRef<HelloComponent>;

@ViewChild('host', {read: ViewContainerRef}) theHost: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private injector: Injector) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
    this.helloRef = factory.create(this.injector);
    this.helloCopyRef = factory.create(this.injector);

    factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(GoodbyeComponent);
    this.byeRef = factory.create(this.injector);
}

show(){
    this.theHost.detach();
    this.theHost.insert(this.helloRef.hostView);
    this.theHost.insert(this.byeRef.hostView);
    this.theHost.insert(this.helloCopyRef.hostView);
}
```

Check this link for demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4aus6a